# added function in ionic keyboard.js breaks cordova inapp browser

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I've added this function into keyboard.js within my ionic.keyboard plugin, but it breaks my inapp broswer plugin. Can anyone help with this?

```
 if( !e.target || keyboardActiveElement !== e.target || !ionic.tap.isTextInput(e.target) || ionic.tap.isDateInput(e.target) || !keyboardIsWithinScroll(e.target) ) return;
```

Comment: First we'd need to know at least the error message you get

Comment: It doesn't give an error message. it stops the inapp browser plugin from working

Comment: Does it stop the plugin from working because you're `return`ing out of whichever function's running so that you're effectively stopping it from running? If that's not it and you get no error, a lot more info is needed.